# How to extract column name (header) from a CSV file which contains the max value in a row?

Tags: shell-script, awk, csv

I am trying to extract the column name with the maximum value in each row using bash script i.e., the column header value or the value from the same column in the first row. I am using the following to extract the max value from each row in a CSV file but can't find out how to print its column name along with the max value:

```
awk -F ',' '{max=$'$col1';for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i > max){max=$i}};print " max: " max}' "$INPUT_PATH/tmp.csv" >>$INPUT_PATH/max1.csv
```

Example:

Sample CSV Data:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
1,5,2,6
4,0,1,2
1,2,0,0
0,0,7,0
```

Desired Output:

```
col4 6 2
col1 4 1
col2 2 2
col3 7 3
```

Is there a way to do this in the above command or is there a better way to extract the desired information from the CSV file?

Comment: what's the values of the third column of your output?

Comment: @AnkitVashistha there a lot of replies. Is none good for you?

Comment: Is that third field of your Desired Output meant to be column number? In which case it would be _4_ on the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions which set the initial value `mx=0` will fail where all fields in the record are negative. Setting to `$1` is safe and then fields can be looped like @Peter.O.

Just for fun, here is a slight `awk` variant iterating over the `head` array indices rather than creating a counter and looping

```
awk -F',' '
  NR==1{split($0,head,FS); next}
  {x=1; for  (h in head) if ($h>$x) x=h;print head[x], $x }
' file
```

Output

```
col4 6
col1 4
col2 2
col3 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and running

```
 mlr --c2n merge-fields -a max -r "^[a-z]" -o value -k  then put '
  for (key, value in $*) {
    if (value == $value_max && key != "value_max") {
        $fieldName=key;
    }
}' then cut -f fieldName,value_max then reorder -f fieldName,value_max input.csv
```

you will have

```
col4 6
col1 4
col2 2
col3 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tr` and [`datamash`](http://%60datamash%60):

```
tr , '\t' < file.csv | datamash -H max 1-4 | datamash transpose
```

Output:

```
max(col1)   4
max(col2)   5
max(col3)   7
max(col4)   6
```

---

Notes:

- The output can be cleaned up with some `sed` if the leading `max()` isn't wanted.
- If the number of columns isn't specifically known, but is sure to be less than some large number, replace `1-4` with `1-1000`, adding zeroes as needed.
- To get an exact count replace the `4` with `$(head -1 file.csv | tr ,
  ' ' | wc -w)`, or (by parsing the header with *POSIX* shell) `$(read
  x < file.csv; echo ${x##*l};)`.

  With the cleanup, and exact count the resulting uglier code would
  look like:

  ```
  tr , '\t' < file.csv | 
  datamash -H max 1-$(read x < file.csv; echo ${x##*l};) | 
  datamash transpose | sed 's/.*(\|)//g'
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  col1    4
  col2    5
  col3    7
  col4    6
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Your future self (and anyone else having to maintain the software) will thank you if you use a language like Python for this. Of course it's not going to be a one-liner, but at least it's readable Naive pseudo-code goes something like this (completely untested):

```
import csv
import defaultdict

with open('max1.csv') as file_handle:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file_handle)
    headers = csv_reader.next()
    maxes = defaultdict(0) # Or negative infinity
    for values in csv_reader:
       for index in range(len(values)):
           if value > maxes[headers[index]]:
               maxes[headers[index]] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with CSV is it doesn't parse nicely with normal shell tools. They simply don't do it nicely. It *can* be done in trivial cases, but really - a scripting language is the tool for the job.

I'd be thinking more `perl` personally:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new();

open ( my $input, "<", "your_file.csv" ) or die $!;
$csv->column_names( $csv->getline( $input ) );

while ( my $row = $csv->getline_hr( $input ) ) {
    my ( $highest, @rest ) = sort { $row->{$b} <=> $row->{$a} } keys %$row;
    print join( "\t", $highest, $row->{$highest} ), "\n";
}
```

Which if using as input:

```
first,second,third,fourth
1,3,4,5,
5,4,3,2,
1,1,4,1,
```

Will print:

```
fourth  5
first   5
third   4
```

Comment: *"CSVs don't parse nicely"* — this is completely false for *basic* CSV files.  With the "CSV" files that MS Excel uses (with embedded newlines and commas within the double quotes), this is true, but that's not the same thing as a straightforward Comma Separated Value file.  (This is why this site has different tags for [tag:csv] and [tag:csv-simple].)

Answer (score 0):

The following allows for a repeating maximum on the same line.

```
awk -F, 'NR==1 { split($0,head,FS); next }
         { max=0; delete a; 
           for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i>=max){ max=$i; a[max]=a[max]head[i]" ("i"), " }
           print "max " max "\t" substr(a[max], 0, length(a[max])-2)
         }' file
```

input:

```
hdr A,hdr B,hdr C,hdr D,hdr E,hdr F
5,2,7,4,7,-9
1,5,4,3,2,1
1,5,9,9,5,3
```

output:

```
max 7   hdr C (3), hdr E (5)
max 5   hdr B (2)
max 9   hdr C (3), hdr D (4)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear what you are asking, I assume you want to print for every row max value of the row and column header for column in wich this value is found:

```
BEGIN {
    FS = ",";
}
NR == 1 {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        x[i] = $i;
    }
    next;
}
{
    max = $1 + 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if (max <= ($i + 0)) {
             v[x[i]] = $i + 0;
             max = (v[x[i]] >= max) ? v[x[i]] : max;
        }
    }

    printf("Row %d: Column(s): ", NR);
    for (i in v) {
        if (max == v[i])
            printf("%s ", i);
    }
    print "max value: " max;
}
```

You can save above in file.awk and run:

```
awk -f file.awk your input
```

So for given input:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8
-1,-2,-22,-4,-1,-2,-4,-8
-9,-3,-2,-1,-2,-4,-5,-7
0,-3,-2,-1,-10,-11,-2,-8
```

Output should be:

```
Row 2, Colums(s): col1 col5 max value: -1
Row 3, Colums(s): col4 col5 max value: -1
Row 4, Colums(s): col1 max value: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bash solution.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1

OIFS=$IFS
IFS=,
# grab headers
headers=( $(head -1 $FILE) ) 
fields=${#headers[@]}

l=1
while read -a line; do
  (( l==1 )) && (( l-- )) && continue # skip header line
  maxi=0
  for((index=1;index<$fields;index++));do
    (( ${line[$maxi]} < ${line[$index]} )) && maxi=$index
  done
  echo ${headers[$maxi]} ${line[$maxi]}
done<$FILE
IFS=$OIFS
```

The header line is read into `headers[]` and `l` is a "first line flag" that gets unset on first iteration. Other than that, it's just a "find the max in array" function inside a fairly standard `while read -a line` loop.

Output from your sample CSV:

```
col4 6
col1 4
col2 2
col3 7
```

I don't think anyone has figured out yet what the *third* field of output was for. If it's for column number, then you'd need to just add  `$((maxi+1))` at the end of the `echo` line, thus:

```
  echo ${headers[$maxi]} ${line[$maxi]} $((maxi+1))
```

Since bash arrays are zero-indexed, adding one to `maxi` to make it one-indexed.